# How to add third party libraries to a UNO platform WebAssembly project

Tags: c#, uno-platform

I have created a UNO platform .NET solution that contains a WebAssembly project. I intend to add some third party components so I added their UWP NuGet package to the UPW project.

Unfortunately, when I build, I get the following errors in the WebAssembly project:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when processing Grid at line 103:4
(D:\UnoTesting\UnoTesting.Shared\MainPage.xaml) : 
The type {using:Syncfusion.UI.Xaml.Grid}SfDataGrid could not be found --->
System.InvalidOperationException: The type {using:Syncfusion.UI.Xaml.Grid}SfDataGrid could not be found
   at : Uno.UI.SourceGenerators.XamlGenerator.XamlFileGenerator.GetType(XamlType type) at:
   D:\a\1\s\src\SourceGenerators\Uno.UI.SourceGenerators\XamlGenerator\XamlFileGenerator.Reflection.cs, line: 722
```

So when I try to use a library, it has to have NuGet packages available *for each platform (Android, macOS, WebAssembly)*? If there is no package then I should use the Windows Community Toolkit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you want to use a NuGet package with an Uno app or library, then the package must be available for all the platforms you wish to support (typically visible under the `Dependencies` tab on the NuGet page). In this case, the SyncFusion controls aren't available yet.

Windows Community Toolkit is available as an alternative. The `DataGrid` in WCT is supported by the most recent stable releases of Uno. Note for WebAssembly and other non-UWP projects, you'll need to use the Uno-compiled versions of the WCT, which are currently separate NuGet packages: `Uno.Microsoft.Toolkit`, `Uno.Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I wonder whether I could create a fairly complex application with database access and API usage with UWP and then port it to WebAssembly with WCT and Entity Framework Core (or any alternative). Uno holds a big promise yet it is somehow still looks like it needs some more time.

Comment: There's a sample of EntityFrameworkCore running in Uno WebAssembly here: https://sqliteefcore-wasm.platform.uno/, with code available here https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.SQLitePCLRaw.Wasm

Comment: Unfortunately the sample project is not working (see this issue: https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.SQLitePCLRaw.Wasm/issues/7) and when I add the NuGet to a sample project, I get runtime errors:  `Error: System.TypeLoadException: VTable setup of type SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_WebAssembly failed`