# How to display gpkg(geopackage) in c#/ .net?

Tags: c#, .net, gis, arcgis, uno-platform

I am wanting to display a geopackage file in a .net uno platform project. (Because it's uno platform, nuget packages might work differently, that's the way it seems according to this: [How to add third party libraries to a UNO platform WebAssembly project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62574294/how-to-add-third-party-libraries-to-a-uno-platform-webassembly-project), but i'm a beginner so I wouldn't know).

I tried to use ArcGisRuntime, but it threw this error: The 'Esri.ArcGISRuntime' nuget package cannot be used to target 'net7.0' for output type 'Exe'. Only platform-agnostic class libraries or Windows, iOS and Android platforms are supported. I was thinking that this is because it is a uno platform project, but I am not completely sure. If I could fix this error, then ArcGis has a way to display a geopackage, but if there isn't a way to fix that, I'd need another tool. I have also heard of SharpMap, but I have not been able to find any resources on how to use it. I am wanting to make this app for wasm and windows. Thanks!

Comment: The problem was that uno platform has a wasm head, and arcgis doesn't have a wasm package. I've decided to just use the javascript library and interop with the wasm head.